# How to add current url with parameters infront of .attr("href")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have external links `<a href="http://notmysite.com/">Link</a>`
and I'd need to add: `http://myurl.com?url=` **before** the external link's href.

Making it 
`<a href="http://myurl.com/current/page?url=http://notmysite.com/">` 
My current js code:

```
  $.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
      return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
              && (obj.hostname != location.hostname);
  };
  $('a:external').addClass('external').attr("href", window.location+("href"));
```

It doesn't work. I'm guessing it's syntax.

I'm rather new to jquery, so would prefer a dirtier/straight forward approach to this

Cheers!

Comment: You're new to jQuery and you're already extending `$.expr` with custom selectors? Good on ya!

Comment: @logii: After some revision, I feel I've got a satisfactory solution for you below.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: I took the first four lines from somewhere else. Have to admit that I do not understand them at all..

@Jonathan Sampsons: Thanks, your answer was good. I chose Justin's answer to my question instead, because I could play with the var 'gateway' and pull the url from window.location instead.

Thanks all for the answers, really appreciate it.
Will be hanging around stack from now, you guys are amazing =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, which takes care to `escape` the URL before appending it to the gateway URL matches more URLs, and is slightly optimized:

```
var externalLinkPattern = new RegExp("^http://" + window.location.host, "i"),
    gateway             = "http://myurl.com/current/page?url=";

$("a[href^='http:']").each(function() {
    if ( !externalLinkPattern.test(this.href) ) {
        this.href = gateway + escape(this.href);
        $(this).addClass("external");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following:

```
$("a[href^='http:']:not([href*='"+window.location.host+"'])").each(function(){
  $(this)
    .attr("href","http://mysite.com?url="+$(this).attr("href"))
    .addClass("external");
});
```

This HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://localhost/somepage.html">Localhost</a>
```

Becomes this:

```
<a class="external" href="http://mysite.com?url=http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://localhost/somepage.html">Localhost</a>
```

Comment: This is missing some of the possible links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we use on `insightcruises.com`, which rewrites all outbound URLs as prefixed with `http://insightcruises.com/cgi/go/`:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('a[href^=http:]').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var href = $this.attr('href');
                href = href.replace(/#/, '%23');
                var newhref = 'http://insightcruises.com/cgi/go/'+href;
                // $('<p />').text(newhref).appendTo('body');                   
                $this.attr('href', newhref);
            });
    });
window.cgigo = function (url, windowName, windowFeatures) {
    if (url.match(/^http:/)) {
        url = url.replace(/\#/, '%23');
        url = 'http://insightcruises.com/cgi/go/'+url;
    };
    window.open(url, windowName, windowFeatures);
};
```